# I am showing an image for 'next page' button. but it is not displaying on screen

Tags: html, css

I am showing an image hyperlink for 'nex page' option. but that image is not visible on screen. my page looks like this...

['next page' button's image is not visible on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTXFF.png)

The below is the CSS code of this image button - webpage developed using extJs

```
.ext-gecko .x-btn button, .ext-webkit .x-btn button {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.x-btn-icon .x-btn-text {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.x-btn button {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.x-btn button {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333;
}
.x-btn button {
    border: 0 none;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    outline: 0 none;
}

.x-tbar-page-next {
    background-image: url(images/grid/page-next.gif) !important;
}
.x-btn-text {
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
}
```

could you help me to find a solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your path is incorrect. Try

```
.x-tbar-page-next {
    background-image: url(../images/grid/page-next.gif) !important;
}
```

Comment: what folders' structure do you have? www/images/..., www/css/... ? also check: whether your image exist in folder and correctness of its name in css file

Comment: Lexxi,,  If I replace the file name page-next.gif with any other image(green,red colors)  name then image displayed.

For all other images with black/white color those images are not visible....   could you tell me the solution?? 

Is there any change required in backgound-color...etc.

Comment: if it exist on page but you can't see it because it is black on black background, then change the background/change the image/ add white `box-shadow`/ add `outline` or `border`... a lot of options

Comment: hi lexxi, the mentioned images in the path /images/grid/  are not available, later i added. thanks for your clue